# VSC: Annoying warning .Net needs to be installed

Tags: .net, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have recently started using Visual Studio code for angular 2 development in typescript.

However from time to time VSC keeps throwing warning messages, especially when I save any file. Message:

> .Net 3.5 needs to be installed.

I don't understand why this comes up, when I am only using typescript, I am not even using VSC's compiler. Everything works smoothly except this annoying message. Any idea how I can block this completely, I have no plans of using .NET in foreseeable future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  the error message suggests, installing the .NET Framework is the obvious solution to that issue. Furthermore, the official site for Visual Studio Code [mentions the .NET Framework as a requirement for VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements) - at least on Windows. So if you are on Windows, and I suppose you are, then you have to install .NET for VSCode, whether you like it or not.

Comment: Software requirement does sate so, but there has to be a way to disables this, I can't install unnecessary softwares on my work pc

Comment: Why? You obviously were able to download/install VSCode on your work PC, so another software should not be that much of a problem. And if it is a dependency of the software you need for your work (VSCode), then it is even justified to install the .NET framework.